# How do you perform an if then else statement as a concatenation?

Tags: c#, if-statement

For example:

```
StringBuilder list1 = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder list2 = new StringBuilder();


sb.Append("alert('Operation has been submitted, however, the following files were not valid and thus operations against their respective courses were not processed: "
 + if x == 1 display list1.ToString() else if x==2 display list2.ToString() +
". An email will be sent when the process has completed for any applicable valid course IDs.");
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I wanted to point out `String.Format` *may* suit you in case you are not faimiliar with it. MSDN Documentation : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [Ternary Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
string message = x == 1 ? "message1" : x == 2 ? "message2" : "message3"
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. Would've just googled this but didn't know what term to look up, now I know it's ternary.

Comment: Some parentheses might help to clarify since you're performing two ternary operations as the OP isn't familiar with them.